# Post Redirect Get - how is POST never ever ever resubmitted?

Tags: http, http-post, http-get

There are many interesting articles on the Post Redirect Get pattern for example here: http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365146/Redirect-After-Post

But here's a simple question...

If the user does POST and is redirected to a GET. Fine if they hit refresh the browser just sends GET, easy to understand.  But if the hit the BACK button after the GET and then hit refresh they can surely hit the POST again?  yeah?

I am trying to understand how we can be 100% sure the POST can never be resubmitted?

Comment: A point worth making here from some research is that requests that return 302, 303 don't generally go into the browser history. This means when the back is pressed, the browse will not go back to the POST request but to the request before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method for ensuring that a POST is not resubmitted is have a unique identifier associated with that post session, for example, if it's a shopping cart, when they begin checking out, generate a unique ID for that process. Once the checkout has completed (e.g. POST has been sent), remove that ID from the ID's that can be used.

You could also do this by generating a unique key with the form, and if the form is submitted, remove that key from where it is stored.

```php
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo generateUniqueKey(); ?>" />
```

where the generateUniqueKey() function will query a table and insert a unique ID, then return the ID. On the page where you are processing the form, do something like this:

```php
<?php 
    $key = $_POST['key'];
    if (isKeyStillValid ($key)) {
        markKeyAsInvalid ($key);
        // Process form ...
    }
    else {
        die ("You have already submitted this form".);
    }
?>
```

Where the isKeyStillValid() function will check the database to ensure the key used with the form is still a useable key, and the markKeyAsInvalid() function will remove the key from the database.

**Update:**
Here's an example that I just made which involves exactly what I described earlier. This is a very simple example, and simply uses an auto-incrementing ID in a SQL table as the key, but it should be sufficient as an example. Realistically, you would want something more thought out than this.
http://alexloney.com/post/

Comment: thanks. When I first reach that page a hidden key is generated.  How come when I go "back" to that page another hidden key is not generated?

Comment: It works because when the page is requested, it calls the server side PHP script to generate a key. But, when you go "back", your web browser simply loads the cached version of the page, rather than requesting the page all over again. Since it loads the saved version, it will not request the page again, and thus it does not generate a new key.

Comment: Makes sense but you should not be caching such pages should you?

Comment: It depends on how you are wanting it to run. If you want to force the page to not cache, then you will need another way of tracking if the form has not been validated, such as storing an identifier in a cookie that would inform you that the form has already been submitted. Or, you could store the form ID, along with the user ID (if they have to be logged in to submit the form) in a table, to tell if they have already submitted the form. Although, if you force the page to reload when the user uses the Back button, it will probably clear out the form contents.

Comment: If you're using PHP, adding these two lines at the top of your page should force the page to be revalidated when the user visits the page (if you're using another language, I'm sure there's a way to send headers with it too) `header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");` and `header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");`

Comment: this is not a answer, it is just walk around.

Comment: this is not a answer, it is just walk around. does the post/redirect/get pattern fix the go back issue also?  seems yes based on the test i did.  but why?  when a url will go to the browser's history that go back can access? requests that return 302, 303 don't generally go into the browser history. it this true?

Answer (score 0):

> But if the hit the BACK button after the GET and then hit refresh they can surely hit the POST again? yeah?

Yeah.

When the user uses the back button, this can happen - the pattern doesn't protect against that, just against having the result coming up in the **same** page as the original form, where a refresh (F5) would cause a repost.

> how we can be 100% sure the POST can never be resubmitted?

One way is to check the posted values against all values submitted in the last X minutes, discarding duplicates (at the risk of losing intentional duplicates).